# How to compute the minimal area of paper required needed to wrap the cubes of same size are stacked together?

Tags: algorithm, math

Reference: https://onlinejudge.org/external/103/10365.pdf

## Expected output as below.

Assuming the Cubes are all of same size 1x1x1 inch dimension

- For 9 cubes to wrap together, the minimal paper size is 30 Square
  inches
- For 10 cubes to wrap together, the minimal paper size is 34
  Square inches
- For 26 cubes to wrap together, the minimal paper size
  is 82 Square inches
- For 27 cubes to wrap together, the minimal paper
  size is 54 Square inches
- For 100 cubes to wrap together, the minimal
  paper size is 130 Square inches

## My thoughts on the solution

For 9 cubes to be wrapped together, the minimal paper required is as follows.

- Solution#1
  Imagine all the cubes are arranged next to each other in one single row horizontally. There are in total 9 cubes one next to each other. The width of the paper must be 10 inches long and 1 inch tall. As there are 4 sides with 9 inches long and 2 sides with 1 inch long, the total paper area required would be 4*10 = 40 square inches.
- Solution#2
  Stack rows of 3 cubes on top of another. We have a square of 3x3. The area would be 6*3^2 = 54 square inches

I could not come up with a better solution with minimal paper area required as 30 square inches as expected !!!

Comment: Please clarify, why each of the remaining 4 sides have only 3 square inches area ?
Can you draw a picture of it ?

Comment: Ok, I am able to visualize the blocks as per your suggestion and able to compute the minimal as expected. 
Thank you very much for quick help :)

Comment: 4*40+2*1.4 = 162.8 square inches ?

Comment: This looks more complex to me and I will need more time to understand this model

Comment: Oh ok. I appreciate for all the help provided

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've figured it out. The important point in the PDF which you failed to include in your question above is that the solution is required to be a rectangular block X x Y x Z. In which case, the surface area S is 2*(XY + XZ + YZ). For simplicity, assume X <= Y <= Z.

Then, for input 9, it must be 1 x 1 x 9 or 1 x 3 x 3 giving S_9 = 2*(1 + 9 + 9) = 38 or S_9 = 2*(3 + 3 + 9) = 30.

For 10, it must be 1 x 1 x 10 or 1 x 2 x 5 giving S_10 = 2*(1 + 10 + 10) = 42 or S_10 = 2*(2 + 5 + 10) = 34.

For 26, it must be 1 x 1 x 26 or 1 x 2 x 13 giving S_26 = 2*(1 + 26 + 26) = 106 or S_26 = 2*(2 + 13 + 26) = 82.

...and so on. So, to solve, you could just try all the ways of factoring the input N into 3 factors and then take the one with the minimum surface area.

Comment: @KJ Oh yeah I missed that line about C. I think for N it means each input N_i. <= 1000. I'll change it to X, Y, Z, but it's sill the same idea. As for your other calculations, I don't know what numbers you're talking about. Maybe you're answering a different question. I don't think it's meant to be 'real world'.